# How does sql distinct work?

Tags: sql

I have known distinct and its usage

My question is how distinct runs fast.
For example , I have 1 million records and Iwant to execute this query

```
select distinct * from table
```

at this point,I wonder if distinct compares the current record with all records.

If so, how can it be so fast?

Comment: it has been asked many times,but nobody has answered correctly,if you know the answer,tell us.If not ,please dont inflate the db of stackoverflow

Comment: Logic says if you can evaluate answers to be false, you have to know true answer. If you know the true answer, then why are you asking?

Comment: What rdbms are you using? Do you have a unique index/primary key  column? If so, it's obvious why it is fast, the rows don't need to be sorted, all that match the `WHERE` clause will be returned.

Comment: `distinct *` makes **no** sense whatsoever. Using * will include the primary key column(s) of the table and thus all rows are distinct per definition and therefor the `distinct` operator cannot remove any duplicates.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're assuming there is a primary key.

Comment: @DStanley: a table without a primary key makes even less sense.